# PHP CLI include() isn't finding the file

Tags: php

Structure of my files is like so:

```
config.php
script
|--myscript.php
```

myscript.php

```
<?php
require '../config.php';
?>
```

When executing `php /path/to/myscript.php` I get `Warning: require(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.`

Whats the reason?

Comment: Try it with an absolute path, instead of a relative one.

Comment: yep, im very disappointed now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's because your current working directory is the one you call your command at, not the one your script is located in.

Use

```
require __DIR__ . '/../config.php';
```

instead. `__DIR__` is a const that points to the directory current file is located in.

Answer (score 8):

One way I do it, is like this:

```
php -d include_path=/path/to/config.php script.php
```

-d is used to set INI directives at runtime, so you don't have any changing code/configs/directories.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to (or can't) change the `require` line in your code, just `cd` to the directory that your script expects to be executed within before running your script:

```
cd /path/to
php /path/to/myscript.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use absolute path or change working directory:

`chdir(dirname(__FILE__));`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you got wrong working directory so your relative paths is not pointing where you expect it to. To see how PHP sees it add:

```
echo getcwd();
```

as the 1st line of your script.