# PHP date and paths when running a batch file in windows

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am facing a puzzle, im testing some scripts on my wamp installation. When i do a echo date('d) and i run the script from the browser i see the correct week day, by example, lets say it echo 'Mon', but.. when i execute it from a batch file, the echo shows the next day, by example 'Tue', why this can be happening? I have the correct timezone in my php.ini the windows clock as well, i dont have a clue why this is happening. In the same puzzle, i have a path to a dbconnect file, again, from browser it run ok, but from the batch file it dont find the included path, i solved it writing the full windows path C:/path/to/file.php but i dont understand why, the include is done by the php file executed by the batch file, so the path should be ok right?

If someone can share some lights i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WAMP the CLI uses a separate php.ini file in the PHP installation directory (e.g. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13) rather than the one under the Apache installation so check the settings in that file for running PHP on the command line.

Comment: Thanks bro! You are right, the one under bin/ had a different timezone.

Comment: and any idea about the path?

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377719/php-cli-include-isnt-finding-the-file

Answer (score 1):

Using php through the browser is using the CGI/FPM version and with your command line it is the CLI version.  CLI and server (cgi/fpm) use different php.ini-files. On cli type

> php --ini

To find where your ini file is and correct it.

Comment: Thanks yes, i checked the php.ini under the bin/ folder as @robjingram mention and had a different timezone. Thanks.