# Is it possible to set PHP CLI include_path from environment?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there a way to set (or add to) the PHP include_path from an environment variable when running CLI PHP?  I'm looking for the PHP analog to Java's CLASSPATH or Perl 5's PERL5LIB.  My gut tells me it should be there, but I can't find it.

If there really is no such thing, then I guess the follow-up is: is there a best practice for achieving this?  Keep in mind that, in my case, the include_path should not be the same for all users, or even for every application.

Comment: One word (?): `php.ini`. If I'm correct, it is loaded when using PHP-CLI.

Comment: But, "in my case, the include_path should not be the same for all users, or even for every application".  But, php.ini is, unless I'm missing something

Comment: No, you can have a different file *per* folder. And you can pass an argument to load a different `php.ini` file.

Comment: If you know what path a class is in, then you can explicitly load it from the fully-qualified path, rather than from a relative expression that needs resolving with include paths.

Comment: If you look at the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) You can see you can use the `-c <file>` arguments or the `-d foo[=bar]` in which `foo` is the name of the key and you set the value (e.g.: `php -d include_path='/my/folder/with/files' /file/to/run.php`).

Answer (score 0):

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24474100/135114) points out that you can use the `-d` argument to set `include_path` in the CLI.

> ```
> php -d include_path=/path/to/config.php script.php
> ```
>
> -d is used to set INI directives at runtime, so you don't have any changing code/configs/directories

*Note: @Ismael answered this in a comment, I just moved the info to an answer, where it stackoverflowily should be.*