# php script executed through ssh doesn't work but work though browser

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script working when ran through a browser https://mywebsite/cron.php but not through ssh.
I'm running `php -f /path/to/the/script/cron.php` and I receive errors like `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MYCLASS' not found`.

The cron.php contains code like that:

```
<?php
require_once("fonctions.php");
$var=new MYCLASS();
```

The fonctions.php :

```
<?
require_once("MYCLASS.php");
```

I tried to use `cd /path/to/the/wwwroot` before `php -f ...` but that doesn't work.
I also tried `chdir(__DIR__)` in the cron.php.

Comment: This looks quite 'foo-bar'ish to me.  `Class 'MYCLASS" not found` suggests that the require worked, but the php file contains no 'MYCLASS' class. Did this really work via browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `__DIR__.'/'`

cron.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__."/fonctions.php");
$var=new MYCLASS();
```

fonctions.php

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__."/MYCLASS.php");
```

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation about what the actual issue was and how/why does this would solve it.

Comment: Are you calling the script via ssh or cronjob ? If you are calling it via cron, make sure you specify full path of php. You can find where php is by calling `whereis php` in shell. Then set cron job like `/usr/bin/php /path/to/the/script/cron.php` Also this might be a related issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377719/php-cli-include-isnt-finding-the-file

Comment: I first tried from cron but as it didn't work I tried from ssh command line, and had that issue...